# Auto-scrolling a PDF on a page basis

Tags: windows-7, pdf

I am looking for a program that can auto-scroll PDF on a page basis. By page basis I mean I want the PDF to auto-scroll page by page, and not by small increments which is the default behavior when selecting "Automatic Scroll" or "AutoScroll" in [Adobe Acrobat Pro XI](https://superuser.com/q/833293/116475) or [Foxit Reader 7](https://superuser.com/q/833479/116475).

If possible,

- can specify how long the auto-scroll should stay on one page
- allow to pause the auto-scroll
- Windows 7
- free.

Comment: Possible workaround: Full screen mode in Foxit Reader plus an autoclick software (or autopress the spacebar) with customizable click intervals